# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net MVC page becomes unresponsive after debugging for about a minute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

When I am running an MVC app in debug mode in vs 2015 community with Update 3, the page becomes unresponsive after about a minute even though debugging is still active. It's as if the page loses it's connection to the running vs instance.  When I attempt to refresh the page or navigate elsewhere in the app, it just sits there trying to load but never does. I always have to restart debugging.  This is really annoying as a developer to constantly have to restart the site - especially when only making javascript or html changes.

I believe this started approximately 6 weeks ago.  I don't recall any change or addition that preceded it.  At first I thought it was just with one solution or browser but have since confirmed it is with every solution and 3 different browsers.  During this time I installed the same setup on another computer only to have the same problem.

Is there a setting or something I don't know about that causes this?

Comment: Are you using a database? Does this happen always or just when your app uses database?

Comment: Dave81, I am connecting to a db.  After reading your response I created a new MVC test solution that only has the default Home, About and Contact setup that occurs when you first make one in visual studio.  I have left it running for several hours now and when I return to it, it has no problems navigating to another page in the solution.  So at this point it would appear that this is limited to those that connect to a db.

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I have two laptops and my solution works just fine on one but not on the other. Also my mvc app published to azure works just fine. Here's I've found out so far:

Comment: If I open a page (view) and the view controller is using a dbcontext everything works just fine until the same dbcontext is accessed again (go back to previous page and come back). Not much but I haven't had time to dig deeper.